# group rows by specific value in one column and calculate the mean in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

the sample tensor:

```
tensor([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],  # class1
        [ 6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11.],  # class3
        [12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17.],  # class2
        [18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23.],  # class0
        [24., 25., 26., 27., 28., 29.].  # class1
])
```

the expected result:

```
tensor([[18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23.], # class0
        [12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17.], # class1
        [12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17.], # class2
        [ 6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11.]. # class3
])
```

Is there a pure PyTorch method to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

You can add according to class index using [`index_add`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.index_add_) and then divide by the number of each label, computed using [`unique`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.unique):

```py
# inputs
x = torch.arange(30.).view(5,6)  # sample tensor
c = c = torch.tensor([1, 3, 2, 0, 1], dtype=torch.long)  # class indices

# allocate space for output
result = torch.zeros((c.max() + 1, x.shape[1]), dtype=x.dtype)
# use index_add_ to sum up rows according to class
result.index_add_(0, c, x)
# use "unique" to count how many of each class
_, counts = torch.unique(c, return_counts=True)
# divide the sum by the counts to get the average
result /= counts[:, None]
```

The `result` is as expected:

```py
Out[*]:
tensor([[18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23.],
        [12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17.],
        [12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17.],
        [ 6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11.]])
```

Comment: if the input is 3D tensor, Can I do these without loop?